How to convert JSON file into a Pandas dataframe correctly?
I have a JSON file called "values.json" with this content:
{
  "values": [{
    "id": 2,
    "value": "passed"
  }, {
    "id": 41,
    "value": "passed"
  }, {
    "id": 73,
    "value": "passed"
  }, {
    "id": 110,
    "value": "failed"
  }, {
    "id": 122,
    "value": "failed"
  }, {
    "id": 234,
    "value": "passed"
  }, {
    "id": 238,
    "value": "passed"
  }, {
    "id": 345,
    "value": "passed"
  }, {
    "id": 653,
    "value": "passed"
  }, {
    "id": 690,
    "value": "failed"
  }, {
    "id": 5321,
    "value": "passed"
  }, {
    "id": 5322,
    "value": "failed"
  }]
}

I try to convert it to dataframe with next code:
values_path = "values.json"
df = pd.read_json(values_path)
with open(values_path) as f:
    d = json.load(f)
df = pd.json_normalize(d)
print(df)

However, I get the table with one column and one row:
                                              values
0  [{'id': 2, 'value': 'passed'}, {'id': 41, 'val...

My desired output would be something like that:




id
value




0
2
passed


1
41
passed


2
73
passed



What do I do wrong? Or maybe there is something wrong with my JSON file? I will be thankful for any help!

What output do you expect?

I expect to see a table with two columns named "id" and "value" and corresponding data in each row.

Is it on purpose that df is first defined as a read_json, then overwritten, after opening the file, as a json_normalize

I didn't even know that "with" statement provides loop, I'm not sure how to handle normalization properly... I'm fairly new in Python, to be honest.

@FeelTD Please [edit] to add your desired output. For reference: [mre] and How to make good reproducible pandas examples

@wjandrea I've added the table which represents my desired output, will it do?

@FeelTD Yeah, that'll do. Ideally it's best to put the whole thing or use smaller example input data, but the structure of this data is simple so it's fine.

The data you want is inside the values key, so you just need to select it:
df = pd.json_normalize(d['values'])

      id   value
0      2  passed
1     41  passed
2     73  passed
..   ...     ...
9    690  failed
10  5321  passed
11  5322  failed

[12 rows x 2 columns]


May I ask what should I do if I have another JSON file with nested keys in it? For example

@FeelTD If you want to convert it to a dataframe? It depends what output you want. You could ask a new question if you wanted, but there are some existing questions you could look at first, like say Convert deeply nested JSON to Pandas dataframe

Since this is a flat object there isnt a reason to use normalize. Using d["values"] will raise a key error if it can't find the key. Using .get will return none and return an empty df.
with open("values.json") as f:
    d = json.load(fp=f)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d.get("values"))


Why .get()? Surely you'd want an error if the data's not there, no?

Kindly provide some explanation as to why this is going to work.

import pandas as pd
import json

with open("values.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
df = pd.json_normalize(data["values"]
print(df)

